# What is the best approach to pick range of numbers again and again from the range of numbers?

Tags: numbers, stack, array-algorithms

Let's suppose I have an array of 200 numbers from 1 to 200. If a user want to pick numbers from range 5 to 60 at a time. And next time, again if he wants to pick number from range next time, what is the best approach to check the numbers of range before used. Hit and trial is not best approach. How can we achieve this without? Is there any way around to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: If the new range is say 5 to 70. Do you want to use the result of range 5 to 60 since it is already been picked and only want to pick 61 to 70 now?

Comment: if a user picks 5 as first range, then it should show as its already used. However if a user picks 61, it should show as its available.

Comment: Are you trying to ask that the user won't be able to pick the number from the range that he already picked before or the number can't be picked which has been already picked by the user?